# facebook error Metric requires app admin privileges

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I'm trying to access Facebook insights `payments_daily_spend` with the API with this url:

> https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/APPID/app_insights/payments_daily_spend?since=1403506800&until=1412146800&summary=true&date_format=U&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN

but all I'm getting back is

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#3003) Metric requires app admin privileges",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 3003
    }
}
```

The app access token I'm using was gotten with an account that has admin privileges for the app, and I can't seem to find any reference to this error anywhere. Has anyone seen this before or know what's wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. No idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got an answer by submitting a ticket to Facebook. You need an access token with the `read_insights` extended permission. You can get it from the Graph API Explorer, but there's probably an API call for getting such a token.